# Check format of user inputted time before passing to strtotime

Tags: php, datetime

I'm working on an exercise in which I accept a user defined [timestamp](/questions/tagged/timestamp) with day, month, year, hour, min, sec and then display said time with variations across several timezones while also considering every scenario including invalid input.

My question is, how do I compare the format of a string to time before converting it to time?  I first attempted to do it like so but learned that date() will not accept a string.

```
$format = 'd-m-Y h:i:s';
$queryTime = $_POST['day'] . "-" . $_POST['month'] . "-" . $_POST['year'] . " " . $_POST['hour'] . ":" . $_POST['min'] . ":" . $_POST['sec'];
$checkInput = date($format, $queryTime) == $queryTime;

if (date($format,$queryTime) == $queryTime) {
    $now = strtotime($queryTime);
} elseif (date($format,$queryTime) !== $queryTime) {
    $prompt = "Your input is invalid datetime.  Try again.";
    echo '<script>alert('.$prompt.');</script>';
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter of `date()` must be a timestamp. Use `strtotime()` to convert your date into a timestamp:

```
if (date($format, strtotime($queryTime)) == $queryTime) {

} elseif (date($format,strtotime($queryTime)) !== $queryTime) {
```

The last line really could just an `else` statement.

```
if (date($format, strtotime($queryTime)) == $queryTime) {

} else {

}
```

Comment: It's always a slap on the forehead. Thank you, sir.